How do I batch apply Exif notes Nomacs photo manager?
How do I batch “notes” in Exif metadata vs putting a note on one photo at a time?
In Nomacs software the note is added to the Exif file.

Are you OK to use other software?

I’m still a novice in Nomacs’ capabilities. I like its features and open source status.

Check XNView MP, it is not opensource but have a lot of features

According to this page, Nomacs writes "Notes" into the EXIF:ImageDescription. Not many programs will read this tag. XNView doesn't, instead writing to the more common IPTC and XMP locations. I believe Adobe Bridge will write to ImageDescription when you write to the "Description" text box. This will also write the IPTC and XMP tags as well.

@StarGeek Please read: Please put your answers in the answers section, even if they're short and Criteria for determining if a post should be a comment or an answer

@MichaelC I'm not going to put something as an answer when I don't 100% believe that it is the correct answer. In this case, I only explained the underlying details and I don't have Nomacs installed to do further testing. I did not have an answer for the original question, which was "How do I batch “notes” in Exif metadata vs putting a note on one photo at a time?"
